# Storm, if I set the number of executor of one specified bolt to 1, then will the bolt be running on one fixed host all the time?

Tags: apache-storm

As above, I want one bolt to run on only one host. So if I set the executor number of it to 1, can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Just a general comment. You asked many question recently, but never accepted any answer. It would be nice if you would mark answers as accepted (if appropriate) or clarify why an answer did not solve your problem. SO is reputation based and it only works if credit is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It runs on one host but if that Worker process crash it is probable to run on another host.